# How can I get the requestUrl from org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest in Spring MVC like we do using HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

How can I get the URL from WebRequest in Spring MVC like we get through HttpServletRequest (getRetuestUrl())?

Answer (score -3):

Spring provides the option to add `HttpServletRequest` as method parameter. Spring will auto inject this parameter when the controller is invoked.

Here is the code.

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"new", "standard/new"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
}
```